# How to render JSON array from LWC as a table in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

I have a LWC with a datatable. I need to generate a PDF of this datatable. How can I pass the JSON string which populates the datatable to a VF page and render the table there? See what I have so far below:

JSON string to be displayed as a table on VF page:

```
[{"Id":"a0O25000007dzxYEAQ","Amount__c":3321,"Balance__c":23232,"Effective_Date__c":"2022-06-06","Name":"Test Street","Type_Name__c":"Deposit","Mortgage_Account_Name__c":"My Other
Mortgage"},{"Id":"a0O25000007dzxTEAQ","Amount__c":500,"Balance__c":3333,"Effective_Date__c":"2022-05-31","Carton Grove","Type_Name__c":"Deposit","Mortgage_Account_Name__c":"Luke
Primary"}]
```

PrintJobPDFController.cls

```
public with sharing class PrintJobPDFController {
    public String transactions { get;set; }

    @AuraEnabled 
    public static String getPdfFileAsBase64String(string transactions) {
        PageReference pdfPage = Page.TransactionStatement;
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('transactions', transactions);
        Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent();
        String base64Pdf = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdfBlob);
        return base64Pdf;
    }
}
```

TransactionStatement.page

```
<apex:page controller="PrintJobPDFController" renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" cache="true" readOnly="true">
    <apex:outputText value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.transactions}"></apex:outputText>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Transactions">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.transactions}" var="tran">
         <apex:column value="{!trans.Amount__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Currently I get an error when trying to deploy TransactionStatement.page

```
Unknown property 'PrintJobPDFController.trans'
```

I have also tried using JSON2Apex which gives me the below but I'm not really sure how to use it properly

TransactionParser.cls

```
public class TransactionParser {

    public String Id {get;set;} 
    public Integer Amount {get;set;} 
    public Integer Balance {get;set;} 
    public String EffectiveDate {get;set;} 
    public String Name {get;set;} 
    public String TransactionDate {get;set;} 
    public String MortgageAccountAddressLine1 {get;set;} 
    public String TypeName {get;set;} 
    public String MortgageAccountName {get;set;} 

    public TransactionParser(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'Id') {
                        Id = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'Amount__c') {
                        Amount = parser.getIntegerValue();
                    } else if (text == 'Balance__c') {
                        Balance = parser.getIntegerValue();
                    } else if (text == 'Effective_Date__c') {
                        EffectiveDate = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'Name') {
                        Name = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'Transaction_Date__c') {
                        TransactionDate = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'Mortgage_Account_Address_Line_1__c') {
                        MortgageAccountAddressLine1 = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'Type_Name__c') {
                        TypeName = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'Mortgage_Account_Name__c') {
                        MortgageAccountName = parser.getText();
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'TransactionParser consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static List<TransactionParser> parse(String json) {
        System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
        return arrayOfTransactionParser(parser);
    }
    
    public static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }
    
    private static List<TransactionParser> arrayOfTransactionParser(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<TransactionParser> res = new List<TransactionParser>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new TransactionParser(p));
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```